# am getting a variable value as zero even it assigned with some value in java

Tags: java

I have 3 classes, among the classes, I am trying to play with methods for that from **Second** class I am passing some values into **First** class and from there I am passing values to third class

in the **Third** I am combining 3 parameters and storing in a variable called **p**.

now I am trying to print **p** value in **Second** class using a method which returns **p** value but it printing as zero but in the setFive() method it printing the actual value.

Please help me with this where i am doing wrong

**Tried Code:**

```
class First {
    int x, y, z;

    void setOne(int a, int b, int c) {
        a = a + x;
        b = b + y;
        c = c + z;
        Third obj = new Third();
        obj.setFive(a, b, c);
    }

    void two(int a) {
        this.x = a;
    }

    void three(int a) {
        this.y = a;
    }

    void four(int a) {
        this.z = a;
    }
}

class Second {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        First f = new First();
        f.two(100);
        f.three(150);
        f.four(170);
        f.setOne(1, 2, 3);
        Third obj = new Third();
        System.out.println(obj.getFive());
    }
}

class Third {
    int p;

    public void setFive(int a, int y, int n) {
        this.p = a + y + n;
    }

    public int getFive() {

        return p;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You create `Third obj = new Third()` in your setOne method, but that is just going to go away because it is a local variable. It has nothing to do with the Third obj in your main method.

Comment: You are creating a new object of Third class. 

Use the keyword [static](https://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java) as :
static int p;

Comment: @Vaibhav bro making p as static it is working but can i know why it is not working since in First class am doing assignment operation in setOne method but there x y z values not  becomes default value(0) , holding their values but in third class it becoming default value ?can i know bro

Comment: @matt Yeah I get that. Using the 'static' keyword is one solution for the problem. Here, two different objects/instances of the same class are created. By using static, for both the objects/instances same copy of the variable p will be maintained. Another solution for this problem would be to use a global variable and set its value to p in the setFive method, but that won't be good as it wouldn't use any Object Oriented Programming Concept.

Comment: @HarishNune
You are assigning some value to p in the First class by calling an object of Third Class. But then while printing the value of p in the Second class you create another object of Third Class. And both these instances have different copy of data. They do not point to the same location in the memory. That's why you are getting the default value = 0 by printing p in the Third class.
By using static, for all the objects of the Third class, same copy of the variable p will be maintained.

Comment: @Vaibhav okay bro Thank you.

Comment: @Vaibhav "...but that won't be good as it wouldn't use any Object Oriented Programming Concept." That is nonsense. Also, another solution is to call setFive on the instance of the variable you call getFive. ie Treat it like an instance of an object.

Comment: @matt Yeah calling setFive before calling getFive is better solution.
Using static is just one of several other methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `Third obj = new Third();` inside `first.setOne(int a,int b,int c)`, this `obj` is local to that method, no other object can see it. It is destroyed when the code exits that method

What you need to do it create that `Third` object in your `Second` class, and then pass it to `First`:

```
Third obj = new Third();
f.setOne(obj, 1, 2, 3);
```

then on `First` you need to change the signature to take the object, and call the setter on it:

```
void setOne(Third obj, int a, int b, int c) {
    a = a + x;
    b = b + y;
    c = c + z;
    obj.setFive(a, b, c);
}
```